# Dos relaciones distintas entre dos tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional, buenas-prácticas

Estoy tratando de volver a mis estudios de programación y tengo una duda con respecto a las relaciones entre dos tablas. Tengo dos tablas Miembro y Asamblea, cada miembro tiene un voto y las decisiones se toman en asambleas, mediante votación.

Entiendo (por el enunciado) que cada miembro puede votar en varias asambleas y que las asambleas pueden recibir varios votos. Lo que sería **una relación muchos a muchos**, pero en caso de querer guardar la información de quién abrió la asamblea(o sea quién la creó) tendría que tener otra **relación de uno a muchos**?

Quiero trabajar con buenas prácticas para crear códigos buenos, pero no sé como resolver esta cuestión.
Hasta ahora lo hice así pero no sé si puede modelar de esta forma, ni si después al pasarlo a código daría redundancia o algún otro error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el enunciado del problema: (Es un desafió back-end para hacerlo en Java)

> En el cooperativismo, cada socio tiene un voto y las decisiones se
> toman en asambleas, mediante votación. A partir de ahí, debe crear una
> solución de back-end para gestionar estas sesiones de votación. Esta
> solución debe ejecutarse en la nube y proporcionar las siguientes
> funcionalidades a través de una API REST: ● Registrar una nueva
> agenda; ● Abrir una sesión de votación en una agenda (la sesión de
> votación debe permanecer abierta durante un tiempo específico en la
> convocatoria de apertura o 1 minuto por defecto); ● Recibir votos de
> los miembros en las agendas (los votos son simplemente 'Sí'/'No'. Cada
> miembro se identifica mediante una identificación única y solo puede
> votar una vez por agenda); ● Contar los votos y comunicar los
> resultados de la votación en el orden del día. A efectos de ejercicio,
> se puede abstraer la seguridad de las interfaces y cualquier llamada a
> las interfaces se puede considerar autorizada. La elección del idioma,
> frameworks y bibliotecas es libre (siempre que no infrinja los
> derechos de uso). Es importante que las agendas y los votos persistan
> y no se pierdan cuando se reinicie la aplicación.

Comment: En general a mi me parece bien el modelo, quizás el voto sea mejor un valor booleano (true/false; 1/0) o eliminar el `ìd` de la tabla `Votos` dejando como PK los campos `Miembro_Id` y `Asamblea_Id` así te aseguras que no se repitan, aunque esto lo puedes controlar desde la API.  Lo que debes entender es que la programación es un proceso iterativo, el modelo no tiene porque quedar perfecto a la primera, a medida que vayas avanzando en el proyecto te vas a dar cuenta si tu modelo cumple tus necesidades y en caso contrario lo ajustas para que lo cumpla

Comment: En general se ve bien. Como observación, el campo miembro_cargo en la tabla asamblea es redundante, si ya tienes el id_miembro (que asumo que es el usuario que crea la asamblea) ya por herencia sabes que cargo tiene ese usuario. Adicional, los nombres de tus campos y tablas deben poseer un estándar, o los defines en ingles o en español, nunca "Spanglish". También concuerdo con @Yussef en que el valor del voto sea un campo booleano.

Comment: Aparte de lo que comentan Yussef y Ernesto (aunque desconocía eso de la "herencia" en este contexto, Miembro_Cargo sobra en Asamblea, sí), yo veo que hay tablas que no se necesitan siquiera a priori según el enunciado presentado, que son las de cargo y categoría. Puedes poner un campo booleano en Miembro para indicar si pueden convocar asambleas o no.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos ! Voy hacer los cambios que me comentaron y continuar con el desarrollo, ahora que me quedó más claro todo. Gracias nuevamente !